# Bigquery: A "READER" but not writer. Can he/she query the table in that dataset within the project that contain the data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have read this over and over again. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/access-control

The question is: If I were to give a user "READER" access to a dataset only. No dataset "Writer" or project "Can Edit" that contains the dataset. This user query the table in the dataset from his/her project and doesn't save it into a table (basically bigquery create a temp table). I guess a better question is, is this temp table being saved in the user project or in the same project as where the data originated.

My assumption is in the project he runs, as the billing account for his/her project is going to get billed for it. Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct assumption. If the user has a READER permission in the dataset and doesn't have access to the project itself, this user won't be able to run queries unless he is part of some project with enabled billing.

Comment: Let add to this:
Let say the user have "Can View" access to the project that have the dataset that he/she is going to query. According to the access control information page: The person can start a job in the project but it depends on the type of job. What it sound like to me is that this person still cannot query the table because he does not have write access to write the data to a temp or perm table. Is this a fair assumption?

Comment: Just tested that for you. I shared a project with another Google user with VIEW only privilege and then shared the dataset with the same user. In fact, I didn't need to share the dataset since by default, the dataset is shared with all project viewers. Then, I logged-in with this new user and I could run queries on the dataset and view the results using BigQuery UI. Even the caching worked (under the hood creates temp table).

However, I couldn't sent my results to a 'destination table' because my account didn't have write permission to create a table.

Comment: Correct. Project level access goes down to every dataset but can be overridden at the dataset level.
So with project level "Can View" = can query but cannot have perm store. 
I think in this case the billing account of that project foot the bill.

Comment: @pompanoSlayer, yes he can query the dataset, just not to create new tables or delete existing tables.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Hope you get as much out of this as me!

Answer (score 0):

The temp table created by a query job is created in the project in which the query job ran.

The temp table will be created as a side-effect of the query even if the user only has "Can View" access to the project, since that's all that's required to run a query.

The only charges incurred are the charges for the query itself, since there are no storage costs incurred for temp tables created by a query.